# Mixed elements and SQL for xml path

Tags: sql, xml, path

I've got a stored procedure that generates xml for a bunch of entities in our database; I didn't write it and the guy that did has gone home for the day, so I'm stuck and need help.

The xml it's generating looks like this:

```
<Updates>
   <Update>....stuff....</Update>
   <Update>....stuff....</Update>
   <Update>....stuff....</Update>
   <Update>....stuff....</Update>
</Updates>
```

I need it to look like this:

```
<Updates>
   <CommentUpdate>....stuff....</CommentUpdate>
   <AttachmentUpdate>....stuff....</AttachmentUpdate>
   <CommentUpdate>....stuff....</CommentUpdate>
   <OtherTypeOfUpdate>....stuff....</OtherTypeOfUpdate>
</Updates>
```

Depending on the value of a particular column. Currently, the part of the stored proc that generates this xml is this:

```
   (select 
    u.ID as '@ID',
    u.CreatedDate as '@CreatedDate',
    (select * 
    from dbo.fsn_GetUserRef(u.CreatedBy, 
          case when @RetDepth = 'COMPLETE' 
           THEN 'FULL' 
           ELSE '' END) CreatedBy
    for xml auto, type),
    u.Type as 'Type',
    u.Text as 'Text',
    u.DocumentId as 'DocumentId'    
   from fusion_Updates u
   where u.atom_id=atom.ID
   for xml path('Update'), root('Updates'), type),
```

Help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to the question [Sql XML Path with different children](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3246587/864341) contains a solution that should work for you.

I don't fully understand the structure of the data returned by the query you specified.  Therefore, I'll give you an example with a simpler structure, and you should be able to adapt it to fit your needs.

Assuming you have an `UpdateEvent` table, with columns `UpdateEventKey`, `EventDateTime`, and `UpdateType`, the following query will give you what you want.

Notice that the table is used twice, in an outer select to generate the variable tag names in the record nodes, and in a sub-select to generate the field nodes.  Also, `PATH('')` is used to omit the record node (since this is already generated in the outer select).

```sql
CREATE TABLE UpdateEvent (
        UpdateEventKey INT,
        EventDateTime DATETIME,
        UpdateType VARCHAR(50)
        );
INSERT INTO UpdateEvent (UpdateEventKey, EventDateTime, UpdateType)
        VALUES (1, GETDATE(), 'Comment');
INSERT INTO UpdateEvent (UpdateEventKey, EventDateTime, UpdateType)
        VALUES (2, GETDATE() + (1 / 1440.0), 'Attachment');
INSERT INTO UpdateEvent (UpdateEventKey, EventDateTime, UpdateType)
        VALUES (3, GETDATE() + (2 / 1440.0), 'Comment');
INSERT INTO UpdateEvent (UpdateEventKey, EventDateTime, UpdateType)
        VALUES (4, GETDATE() + (3 / 1440.0), 'OtherTypeOf');

SELECT CAST('<' + U1.UpdateType + 'Update>'
        + (SELECT * FROM UpdateEvent AS U2
                    WHERE U2.UpdateEventKey = U1.UpdateEventKey FOR XML PATH(''))
        + '</' + U1.UpdateType + 'Update>' AS XML)
        FROM UpdateEvent AS U1 FOR XML PATH(''), ROOT('Updates'), TYPE;
```

This generates the following XML.

```xml
<Updates>
    <CommentUpdate>
        <UpdateEventKey>1</UpdateEventKey>
        <EventDateTime>2013-02-14T20:32:41.803</EventDateTime>
        <UpdateType>Comment</UpdateType>
    </CommentUpdate>
    <AttachmentUpdate>
        <UpdateEventKey>2</UpdateEventKey>
        <EventDateTime>2013-02-14T20:33:41.767</EventDateTime>
        <UpdateType>Attachment</UpdateType>
    </AttachmentUpdate>
    <CommentUpdate>
        <UpdateEventKey>3</UpdateEventKey>
        <EventDateTime>2013-02-14T20:34:41.727</EventDateTime>
        <UpdateType>Comment</UpdateType>
    </CommentUpdate>
    <OtherTypeOfUpdate>
        <UpdateEventKey>4</UpdateEventKey>
        <EventDateTime>2013-02-14T20:35:41.777</EventDateTime>
        <UpdateType>OtherTypeOf</UpdateType>
    </OtherTypeOfUpdate>
</Updates>
```